# Access shared mailbox through o365 v2 api

Tags: php, outlook, ms-office, office365

So I got access to the new o365 v2 api and it's working pretty good so far. I am however having trouble accessing any shared inboxes.

Even worse, there doesn't appear to be any error message being returned:

```
@odata.context = https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/$metadata#Me/Messages(Subject,ReceivedDateTime,SentDateTime,Sender,From,ToRecipients,CcRecipients,BccRecipients,ReplyTo,ConversationId,IsRead,InternetMessageId

[value] =
```

Has anyone ever tried this?

To clarify, this isn't for exchange, but outlook.com

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you were using the delegate-token to request the message from the specific user for the messages in a shared box.

The Office 365 REST API only support app-level token to get the messages from the organization. The delegate-token only could get the messages of the delegatee user.

You can also consider using the EWS to retrieve the messages of shared box as a workaround.

Here is an example for your reference:

```
        string userName = "";
        string password = "";

        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1);
        service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);

        service.TraceEnabled = true;
        service.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.All;

        service.AutodiscoverUrl(userName, RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);


        FolderId SharedMailbox = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, "sharedmailbox@consoto.onmicrosoft.com");
        ItemView itemView = new ItemView(10);
        var results = service.FindItems(SharedMailbox, itemView);
        foreach (var item in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Subject);
        }
```

And if you want the Office 365 REST API to support this feature, you can also submit the feedback from [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).

Comment: Thanks. Am I correct in that to request an app-level token I need to add the 'prompt=admin_consent' attribute to the initial request?

As seen here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2014/03/25/using-oauth2-to-access-calendar-contact-and-mail-api-in-office-365-exchange-online/

Comment: No. The app-level token is use the 'Client Credential flow' which use the '**clientId**' and '**client secret**'  to authenticate instead of 'Authorization code grant flow' which require user to sign-in.  Refer to [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/azure/dn645545.aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/azure/dn645545.aspx) about the two basic authenticate flow.

Comment: Thanks for this, looks like this might be the solution. If so, I'll answer and close the question accordingly.